# Ambient modules in other files works with tsc but not webpack + ts-loader?

Tags: typescript, webpack, ts-loader

I'm playing around with learning ambient modules in TypeScript, using a small toy example of MailApp, a global module in Google Apps Script [(see here)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)). What I'm doing is just writing my code in VS code, compiling it with webpack, and then copying this as ES5 code into an Apps Script console to run.

**My issue**: for the below code, when I move the ambient module declaration out to a .d.ts file and use a triple-slash directive to reference it, the TSC and VS code both recognize this. However, webpack + ts-loader (awesome-typescript-loader has same issue) always show an error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'MailApp'
```

Am I missing something here?

My declaration file: root/src/AppsScriptTypes.d.ts

```
declare module 'MailApp' {
  export interface EmailOptions {
    bcc?: string;
    cc?: string;
    htmlBody?: string;
    name?: string;
    noReply?: boolean;
    replyTo?: string;
  }
  export function sendEmail(
    recipient: string,
    subject: string,
    body: string,
    options?: EmailOptions): void;
 }
```

My main file: root/src/SendMail.ts

```
/// <reference path="./AppsScriptTypes.d.ts" />
import * as MailApp from 'MailApp';

MailApp.sendEmail(
  'myemail@gmail.com',
  'Sample Email Title',
  'Sample Email Body', {
    noReply: true,
    cc: 'myemail@gmail.com',
  });
```

My root/webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/SendMail.ts',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: __dirname,
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx',],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        test: /\.(t|j)sx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules|MockMailApp\.js/,
      }
    ]
  },
};
```

When I don't use the triple-slash reference + separate file and move the declaration into the SendMail.ts file, webpack + ts-loader doesn't have an error, but this is not preferable, of course:

```
declare module MailApp {
  ...
} // this works for webpack when shown like this in SendMail.ts

MailApp.sendEmail(...);
...
```

Am I missing a config somewhere? I am using webpack 2.4.1, TypeScript 2.3, ts-loader 2.0.3. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I am having the same issue with ambient module  , webpack suggest Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'Utils'    is someone able to resolve this with webpack ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is going to help but you could try **one** of the following:

1. Add ".d.ts" to the resolve.extensions in your webpack.config.js file
2. Use ".ts" extension instead of ".d.ts" in your AppsScriptTypes.d.ts file